# MSBuild output vs Visual Studio output against a COM interop

Tags: visual-studio, com, msbuild

I am attempting to a get a isolated build environment setup in my dev team.

The problem that I am presently hitting is a DotNet project which has a reference to a VB6 COM assembly.
The COM assembly is registered on the build system, but when I run msbuild against the sln I get the following error:

```
error MSB3303: Could not resolve COM reference "f630637a-718a-41c7-9c52-41f934dc4625" version 3.2. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

The GUID for this assembly is correct, and if I load the solution up in Visual Studio it builds fine and generates Interop.* assemblies as required.

I do not wish to have the Visual Studio build as a requirement in the build steps.

How can I get msbuild from the command line to build the Interop assemblies the same as VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that msbuild does not follow the project dependencies the same way as the IDE - [as per this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272199/why-am-i-missing-assemblies-from-the-bin-directory-when-compiling-with-msbuild)

If I build the specific project that was failing before building the entire solution everything is good.