# Determining outputs of a ProjectReference in MSBuild without triggering redundant rebuilds

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, project-reference

As part of a solution containing many projects, I have a project that references (via a `<ProjectReference>` three other projects in the solution, plus some others). In the `AfterBuild`, I need to copy the outputs of 3 specific dependent projects to another location.

Via various SO answers, etc. the way I settled on to accomplish that was:

```
    <MSBuild 
        Projects="@(ProjectReference)" 
        Targets="Build" 
        BuildInParallel="true" 
        Condition="'%(Name)'=='ProjectA' OR '%(Name)'=='ProjectB' OR '%(Name)'=='ProjectC'">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="DependentAssemblies" />
    </MSBuild>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(DependentAssemblies)" DestinationFolder="XX" SkipUnchangedFiles="true" />
```

However, I ran into problems with this. The `<MSBuild` step's `IncrementalClean` task ends up deleting a number of the outputs of `ProjectC`. When running this under VS2008, a `build.force` file being deposited in the `obj/Debug` folder of ProjectC which then triggers ProjectC getting rebuilt if I do a Build on the entire solution if the project containing this `AfterBuild` target, whereas if one excludes this project from the build, it [correctly] doesn't trigger a rebuild of ProjectC (and *critically* a rebuild of all dependents of ProjectC). This may be VS-specific trickery in this case which would not occur in the context of a TeamBuild or other commandline MSBuild invocation (but the most common usage will be via VS so I need to resolve this either way)

The dependent projects (and the rest of the solution in general) have all been created interactively with VS, and hence the `ProjectRefence`s contain relative paths etc. I've seen mention of this being likely to causing issues - but without a full explanation of why, or when it'll be fixed or how to work around it. In other words, I'm not really interested in e.g. converting the `ProjectReference` paths to absolute paths by hand-editing the .csproj.

While it's entirely possible I'm doing something stupid and someone will immediately point out what it is (which would be great), be assured I've spent lots of time poring over `/v:diag` outputs etc. (although I havent tried to build a repro from the ground up - this is in the context of a relatively complex overall build)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As noted in my comment, calling GetTargetPath on the referenced project only returns the Primary output assembly of that project.   To get all the referenced copy-local assemblies of the referenced project it's a bit messier.

Add the following to each project that you are referencing that you want to get the CopyLocals of:

```
    <Target
    Name="ComputeCopyLocalAssemblies"
    DependsOnTargets="ResolveProjectReferences;ResolveAssemblyReferences"
    Returns="@(ReferenceCopyLocalPaths)" />
```

My particular situation is that I needed to recreate the Pipeline folder structure for System.AddIn in the bin folder of my top level Host project.  This is kinda messy and I was not happy with the MSDN suggested solutions of mucking with the OutputPath - as that breaks on our build server and prevents creating the folder structure in a different project (eg a SystemTest)

So along with adding the above target (using a .targets import), I added the following to a .targets file imported by each "host" that needs the pipeline folder created:

```
<Target
    Name="ComputePipelineAssemblies"
    BeforeTargets="_CopyFilesMarkedCopyLocal"
    Outputs="%(ProjectReference.Identity)">

    <ItemGroup>
        <_PrimaryAssembly Remove="@(_PrimaryAssembly)" />
        <_DependentAssemblies Remove="@(_DependentAssemblies)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <!--The Primary Output of the Pipeline project-->
    <MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.Identity)"
             Targets="GetTargetPath"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)"
             Condition=" '%(ProjectReference.PipelineFolder)' != '' ">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"
                ItemName="_PrimaryAssembly" />
    </MSBuild>

    <!--Output of any Referenced Projects-->
    <MSBuild Projects="%(ProjectReference.Identity)"
             Targets="ComputeCopyLocalAssemblies"
             Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)"
             Condition=" '%(ProjectReference.PipelineFolder)' != '' ">
        <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"
                ItemName="_DependentAssemblies" />
    </MSBuild>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(_PrimaryAssembly)"
                                 Condition=" '%(ProjectReference.PipelineFolder)' != '' ">
            <DestinationSubDirectory>%(ProjectReference.PipelineFolder)</DestinationSubDirectory>
        </ReferenceCopyLocalPaths>
        <ReferenceCopyLocalPaths Include="@(_DependentAssemblies)"
                                 Condition=" '%(ProjectReference.PipelineFolder)' != '' ">
            <DestinationSubDirectory>%(ProjectReference.PipelineFolder)</DestinationSubDirectory>
        </ReferenceCopyLocalPaths>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

I also needed to add the required PipelineFolder meta data to the actual project references.  For example:

```
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Dogs.Pipeline.AddInSideAdapter\Dogs.Pipeline.AddInSideAdapter.csproj">
        <Project>{FFCD0BFC-5A7B-4E13-9E1B-8D01E86975EA}</Project>
        <Name>Dogs.Pipeline.AddInSideAdapter</Name>
        <Private>False</Private>
        <PipelineFolder>Pipeline\AddInSideAdapter\</PipelineFolder>
    </ProjectReference>
```

Answer (score 6):

Your original solution should work simply by changing

```
Targets="Build"
```

to

```
Targets="GetTargetPath"
```

The `GetTargetPath` target simply returns the `TargetPath` property and doesn't require building.

Comment: +1 Thanks, not in a position to verify it definitely worked (lots of water under the bridge since !), but seems a very viable and clean approach.

Comment: YMMV: GetTargetPath only returns the primary output assembly of a project (.DLL/.EXE) If you want _all_ referenced assemblies of that project then need a different technique

Comment: In case anyone else needs to do this for a C++ project the correct target to invoke is Targets="GetNativeTargetPath".

Answer (score 2):

You may protect your files in ProjectC if you call a target like this first:

```
  <Target Name="ProtectFiles">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="obj\ProjectC.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt">
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="_FileList"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <CreateItem Include="@(_DllFileList)" Exclude="File1.sample; File2.sample">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="_FileListWitoutProtectedFiles"/>
    </CreateItem>      
      <WriteLinesToFile 
        File="obj\ProjectC.csproj.FileListAbsolute.txt"
        Lines="@(_FileListWitoutProtectedFiles)"
        Overwrite="true"/>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks/congrats on choosing this puzzler as your first ever SO answer! I personally would be reticent about introducing a dependency on the internals of MSBuild of this nature but yes, this would certainly allow me to achieve the "what files did it write" programmatically! There are a few other "compute the outputs" questions here on SO that this might fit better as an answer to. The main issue here for me is that the `<MSBuild` bit is still messing it's own dependencies up and erroneously causing a build directly after my first one to go rebuilding stuff it has just built.

Answer (score 1):

My [current workaround is based on this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266888/msbuild-copy-output-from-another-project-into-the-output-of-the-current-project), i.e, I have:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <DependentAssemblies Include="
            ..\ProjectA\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectA.dll;
            ..\ProjectB\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectB.dll;
            ..\ProjectC\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectC.dll">
        </DependentAssemblies>
    </ItemGroup>
```

This however will break under TeamBuild (where all the outputs end up in one directory), and also if the names of any of the outputs of the dependent projects change.

EDIT: Also looking for any comments on whether there's a cleaner answer for how to make the hardcoding slightly cleaner than:

```
    <PropertyGroup>
        <_TeamBuildingToSingleOutDir Condition="'$(TeamBuildOutDir)'!='' AND '$(CustomizableOutDir)'!='true'">true</_TeamBuildingToSingleOutDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
```

and:

```
    <ItemGroup>
        <DependentAssemblies 
            Condition="'$(_TeamBuildingToSingleOutDir)'!='true'"
            Include="
                ..\ProjectA\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectA.dll;
                ..\ProjectB\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectB.dll;
                ..\ProjectC\bin\$(Configuration)\ProjectC.dll">
        </DependentAssemblies>
        <DependentAssemblies 
            Condition="'$(_TeamBuildingToSingleOutDir)'=='true'"
            Include="
                $(OutDir)\ProjectA.dll;
                $(OutDir)\ProjectB.dll;
                $(OutDir)\ProjectC.dll">
        </DependentAssemblies>
    </ItemGroup>
```