# How to retrieve @(TargetOutputs) without performing a build

Tags: msbuild, itemgroup

I'm implementing an MSBuild framework to drive the building and deployment of many projects organized as a hierarchy.

```
<Target Name="_CoreBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="Build" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
    <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CompiledAssemblies" />
  </MSBuild>
</Target>
```

In order to implement proper Clean/Clobber logic, I would like to retrieve the list of files that would be compiled if a build were performed with the current options.

```
<Target Name="_CoreClobber" DependsOnTargets="_CoreClean">
   <!-- How to retrieve @(CompiledAssemblies) as if we were
        building @(Project) and retrieving the @(TargetOutputs) item group.
     -->
</Target>
```

I've tried various methods, including creating a custom task, in which I build a custom project file that imports the original project I want to retrieve the properties/items from. But that does not give me reliable values.

Is there a way to retrieve an MSBuild project's TargetOutputs item group without actually performing a build?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never mind.

I stumbled upon [the following similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2325598/determining-outputs-of-a-projectreference-in-msbuild-without-triggering-redundan), and figured I had to use the `GetTargetPath` target, like so:

```
<Target Name="_CoreBuild">
  <MSBuild Projects="@(Project)" Targets="GetTargetPath" Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration)">
    <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="CompiledAssemblies" />
  </MSBuild>
</Target>
```