# How to get paths to all referenced DLLs in MSBuild?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I would like to get paths to all assemblies referenced in a `.csproj` given the following requirements:

- include assemblies no matter how they were referenced (project, nuget, direct `.dll` import)
- do not trigger a build

There is a [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7837907/318795) about how to do it for project references:

```
<MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectReference)" Targets="GetTargetPath">
  <Output TaskParameter="TargetOutputs" ItemName="MyReferencedAssemblies" />
</MSBuild>
```

Is there a similar way to get `.dll` paths of all other types of references?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is seems to be a clean way to do it:

```
  <Target Name="GatherReferences" DependsOnTargets="ResolveReferences">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyReferencedAssemblies Include="@(ReferencePath)" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

After that `MyReferencedAssemblies` item group contains a collection of all referenced DLLs (full paths, all kinds). It also works for `PackageReference` imports in the new `.csproj` format. Important part is that `@(ReferencePath)` is non-empty only after `ResolveReferences` finishes.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like TargetOutput's will give you want you want, since you are looking for inputs.

This should be a trivial matter if you use the MSBuild API (using c#). You can can see how I extended the `Project` class to include just such a thing:

https://github.com/chris1248/SolutionBuilder/blob/master/MSBuildTools/ProjectBase.cs

specifically look at the function:

```
protected int GatherReferenceAssemblies()
```

Comment: Thank you for the hints. In fact I could use MSBuild API, as I pass gathered referenced assemblies into a custom `Task`. I could use the API from there directly. Anyway, my reasoning is: since MSBuild must know these references to build a project, there should be a way to access it. [I found a way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611221/318795), which seems to enable this.